# Understanding this definition of a Random Variable

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

[image: m]

the definition of a random variable above confuses me because it seems to say that the function in question should be mapping both to and from $\Omega$.

If we can input a member of F, the $\sigma$-algebra of Omega into the inverse image and get a member of F then how does this function map from Omega to the real line?

Example:

X: $\Omega$ --> R

$X^{-1}(B)$ is in F for every B in F.

Say $\Omega$ is the outcome of tossing two fair coins.

Then $\Omega$  = { {HH} , {HT} , {TH} , {TT} }

Say F, a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ is given by {{HH, HT}, {TH, TT}, {$\emptyset$}, {$\Omega$}}

Then B is one of the elements given in F above.

If we select B to be {HH, HT} (the event that the first toss is a head) then the definition above says:

$X_{-1}$( {HH, HT} ) is in F.

This says the $X^{-1}$( {HH, HT} ) = one of the elements of F (i.e.  one of { {HH, HT}, {TH, TT}, {$\emptyset$}, {$\Omega$} } ).

However none of the elements of F are real numbers. So if the definition holds (and I understand it correctly) then in what sense does $X$ map from $\Omega$ to R?

This result seems to imply the X maps from Omega to Omega rather than from Omega to R.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a typographical error in your source.

Since $X$ is a function of type $\Omega \to \mathbb R,$
unless $\Omega = \mathbb R$ it is not possible that we can require $B$ and $X^{-1}(B)$ to be members of the same set.
Rather, $B$ should be a member of some class of subsets of $\mathbb R.$

So I agree with you: this definition makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition)

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $(E, \mathcal{E})$ a measurable space. Then an $(E, \mathcal{E})$-valued random variable is a measurable function $X\colon \Omega \to E$, which means that, for every subset $B\in\mathcal{E}$, its preimage $X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$ where $X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega : X(\omega)\in B\}$

In your quote $E$ is $\mathbb R$, but there seems to be a confusion between the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$